How do I the head of a vector in matplotlib?
I'm plotting an entrance and output vector but the head of the vector is so big that is giving me some problems. Currently I'm using this code
ax.quiver(origins[i, 0], origins[i, 1], origins[i, 2], 
                v2[i, 0], v2[i, 1], v2[i, 2], 
                color='g', length=0.1, alpha=0.5,)

I tried shrinking the head of the vector by adding the parameter width as width, and headwidth which are used in the matplotlib homepage but it doesn't work because there is no parameter width nor headwidth so I don't know what to do.
Sorry if there are some grammatical errors, English is not my first language.
I was expecting the head of the vector to be smaller or a direct way to modify its width

I am a bit confused. Why do you have 6 positional arguments (the origins as well as the v2 arguments). The quiver method accepts at max 5 such arguments. Also, length is not a valid keyword argument. How did you try to use headwidth and width, please show the corresponding code? That does matter, because you should be able to use these keyword arguements.

@Flow perhaps its a 3D quiver plot, which would take 6 positional arguments. Alex could you clarify if this is a 3D plot?

@tmdavison Thanks, that would explain a lot. With this information I could reproduce the problem. This seems to be a long time issue. @Alex Von D: It might help to change the arrow_length_ratio to something less than the default of 0.3. But it also might be that the arrow heads will still look ugly or are not visible at all if I get the issue correctly.

Hi, sorry for not clarify that it was a 3D plot, I will try with the command arrow_length_ratio and will inform if something happens
